# how to update the records in db if we try to insert similar records?

Tags: mongodb

> If we try to insert a similar records then that record shouldn't be
>   inserted instead of that need to be updated
>
> Here is my query

```
db.cos.insert({'subject':'A','batch': '2004','section':'A','cos':[{'code':1,'desc': '1 d','pos': {'po1': 3,'po2': 3.5,'po3': 0,'po4': 2,'po5': 3}}] });
```

> after executing this query one data is inserted, if i try to execute
>   this query again then it shouldn't be saved instead of it should
>   update

Answer (score 0):

You will need the unique ID of the document, and then you can use `db.cos.save(yourDocument)` to update.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/

If you don't provide the unique ID, or if it couldn't find the provided key, a new document will be created.

```
db.cos.save({
    _id: 'hello',
    data: 'world'
});
// a new document will be created:
// {_id: 'hello', data: 'world'}

db.cos.save({
    _id: 'hello',
    data: 'world 2'
});
// the same document will be updated:
// {_id: 'hello', data: 'world2'}

db.cos.save({
    _id: 'hello2',
    data: 'world'
});
// another document will be created:
// {_id: 'hello', data: 'world2'}
// {_id: 'hello2', data: 'world'}

db.cos.save({
    data: 'world3'
});
// another document will be created:
// {_id: 'hello', data: 'world2'}
// {_id: 'hello2', data: 'world'}
// {_id: ObjectID(1), data: 'world'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use {upsert: true}

```
db.cos.update({someQueryToFindDocument}, {'subject':'A','batch': '2004','section':'A','cos':[{'code':1,'desc': '1 d','pos': {'po1': 3,'po2': 3.5,'po3': 0,'po4': 2,'po5': 3}}] }, {upsert:true});
```

If no document is matched according to the query in cos collection, then it will insert, otherwise it will update.